# How to disable the increment and decrement buttons for lightning:inputField that renders a number?

Tags: html5

I have a `lightning:inputField` within a `lightning:recordEditForm`. How can I disable the increment and decrement buttons for ALL fields that render a number? I tried setting the class conditionally to `slds-input` and `slds-input_bare` but no luck. Also note that I have other lightning:inputFields on the page that render a date, picklist, lookups etc which must work as is.

[image]

Comment: Looks like it can be done through CSS [Can I hide the HTML5 number input’s spin box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790935/can-i-hide-the-html5-number-input-s-spin-box) so you have lots of choices over which input elements you apply this to via CSS selectors.

Comment: I agree with Keith. It's nothing to do with lightning component. It is HTML 5 behavior and can be tweaked using css.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to hide the increment/decrement spin box, BUT the number still increments and decrements when I scroll within the textbox with my mouse's scroll wheel. Is there a way to completely disable this functionality as opposed to just hiding it via CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got this to work in entirety. There are two steps involved:

**Step 1: Hide the functionality.** *Credits to Keith and Himanshu for steering me in the right direction.*

To hide the spin box from the UI, put this in STYLE section of your component:

```
.THIS input::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    margin: 0; 
}

.THIS input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    margin: 0; 
}
```

**Step 2: Disable the functionality.** The above just hides the spin box, but the actual functionality still works (i.e. the number changes) when user scrolls using mouse wheel within the textbox or press up/down arrow keys. To remedy that, put this in RENDERER section of your component (or perhaps in the `init` handler instead?):

```
afterRender: function (component, event, helper) {
    this.superAfterRender();

    //disable up, down, right, left arrow keys
    window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        if([37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }, false);

    //disable mousewheel
    window.addEventListener("mousewheel", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }, false);

    window.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }, false);

},
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me with a small change. You can disable using css.

```
.THIS input::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    display:none;
}

.THIS input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the increment buttons with CSS. [Like this](http://w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hide_arrow_number.asp):

```
/* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Firefox */
input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```