# How to disable the increment and decrement buttons for lightning-input field in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a below lightning input field of type number.

```
<lightning-input variant="label-hidden" type="number" step="0.01">
</lightning-input>
```

[image: input field image]

as shown on the above image it adds two unnecessary button to increment and decremente the value, please suggest how to get rid of the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shadow dom is discouraging you to do this as specified by pmdartus [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/246887/target-inner-elements-of-standard-lightning-web-components-with-css).

There is an ugly workaround that you can use. You have to use `renderedCallback` and set the style specified by Atlas Can [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/284986/19118).

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {

     renderedCallback() {
         const style = document.createElement('style');
          style.innerText = 'input::-webkit-outer-spin-button {display:none;}input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {display:none;}';
          this.template.querySelector('lightning-input').appendChild(style);
     }
}
```

Markup:

```
<template>
<lightning-input label="My Number" type="number" step="0.01">
</lightning-input>
</template>
```

Playground Link : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/i9HYzlT_r/2/edit

Src:
https://hellosnl.blogspot.com/2019/07/lwc-override-css-of-standard-lightning-components.html

Comment: Thank you Pranay, it worked as expecteded but it seemed like it slowed down the page, but still thank you again for the work around.

Comment: @gs650x because rendered callback gets called every time a change in ui happens. You can use a Boolean flag to see if you have already assigned style. If u did, don’t enterter again.

Comment: Sure Pranay, will add a boolean flag, thanks

Comment: One last thing Pranay is there any way to remove the step buttons on particular input fields on the page?

Comment: @gs650x you can use name attribute of lighting-input and use complex query selector https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: Thank you so much, Pranay :)

Comment: @gs650x a better way would be to create a sperate components, c-lightning-input without steps that you can reuse .

Comment: I used this code in my LWC but it throws an error - " Cannot read property Appendchild of null  ". Can you please tell me why this happens @PranayJaiswal

Answer (score 4):

Try using this code.

Html code -

```
<template>
<input class="input1" type="number">
</template>
```

And Css Code -

```
.input1::-webkit-outer-spin-button{
    -webkit-appearance: none;

}
.input1::-webkit-inner-spin-button{
    -webkit-appearance: none;

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for responding, but is there any other way to use lightning input field and avoiding the increment and decrement button?

Comment: if you want to hide spin button then you must go by this method.

Comment: Thank You!! @SahilMalhotra This works.

Answer (score 2):

This was asked before for [aura](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/218202/how-to-disable-the-increment-and-decrement-buttons-for-lightninginputfield-that).

```css
.THIS input::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    display:none;
}

.THIS input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: But the above is not working for LWC

Comment: You can try using css selectors https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/input/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disable the step buttons in the lightning-input for type number as this component stands. Omitting step uses the default of 1 for the step size. Trying to set it to 0 or NaN (or any unrecognized value) is treated as if it were set to 1.

See the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/specification) for what you can do.